# Can't resolve parameter to service (?) only in non-AOT mode

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular2-aot, angular2-di

I've seen lots of cases where AoT compilation fails for one reason or another, or generates a weird run-time error. I have the reverse problem: my app **fails in non-AoT mode** with the error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for ConfirmRemoveService (?)

This occurs whether I not I am targeting development or production, and whether or not I am using the `dev` or the `prod` environment. For example, a pure dev build succeeds as long as I also turn on AoT explicitly:

```
ng serve -dev --aot
```

The `?` in the error message above refers to the type `MatDialog`, from the Angular Material2 library. (This `ConfirmRemoveService` is a service used by components to put up a modal dialog.)

This issue may or may not be related to upgrading to the beta 11 version of that library. It may or not be related to my changing from a single import of `MaterialModule` directly from the library, since `MaterialModule` has now been removed, to my own module which imports individual Angular Material2 modules such as `MatDialogModule`; I then import that module where necessary. However, none of these things prevent the application from running in AoT mode; it's just in non-AoT mode that the error manifests itself.

Is anyone aware of a scenario where such a problem could occur only in a **non-AoT scenario**, and why?

Comment: No, the AoT **can** resolve it. It works fine in AoT. It fails if I **don't** use AoT.

Comment: @yurzui A circular dependency between what and what? `MatDialog` is a class within Angular Material2, which certainly doesn't point back to any of my classes. In any case, how could a circular dependency manifest itself in non-AoT mode, but not in AoT mode?

Comment: Instead of fooling yourself with unnecessary questions, why it works, and why it does not work, it's best to create a program where you can see where it's working incorrectly.

Comment: @RomanC Thanks for the advice. That is my next step and what I am working on right now. However, this is a big app and stripping it down to the minimal version that recreates the bug is no trivial task, which is why I chose to post the general question first in hopes someone might have useful ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This problem turns out to have been due to a missing line in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true
```

I think I removed this at some point in a fit of housekeeping, thinking that it was only necessary when compiling Angular-friendly libraries.

My suspicion is when running under AoT, `ngc` is used instead of `tsc`, and `ngc` provides this setting by default, thus accounting for the bug manifesting itself only in non-AoT mode.

Comment: ngc doesn't provide this setting by default it collects metadata by using metadata collector that uses typescript api for reading decorators provided on typescript node

Comment: This answer should be an edit of the question, since it doesn't answer the question even without a clear problem statement.

Comment: The question is why I was getting the error message. The answer gives the solution to making the error message go away. That's usually how it works: the question is some problem, and the answer is a solution to the problem. It's a mystery to me why you would have such a difficult time understanding the basic notions of "questIon" and "answer".

Comment: Please try and reign in the rude comments. It's still profanity if it's masked. If someone says something inane and/or that you disagree with, you are not obligated to respond.

Comment: i'm having a similar problem: aot compilation works, non-aot compilation results in "Can't resolve all parameters" runtime errors. ```"emitDecoratorMetadata": true``` *is* present in my tsconfig.json file. I've been using aot for weeks of commits, and now have run out of time to fix this :(. hooked on aot